# Why did people love Deadpool (2016)?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

It really hits me as I try to understand how people think about movies. The only thing I find interesting in the movie is the high-profile, very intense, tough action at the beginning of the movie. That's quite original, with all the comedy flavor. That was quite interesting.

But with an objective look at the story of the movie... I can tell the story in less than 2 minutes... as a cliché story that was remade many times...

Here it goes: A "hero" who wants something from a bad guy and pisses him off while trying to get it, and the bad guy takes the love of his life as a hostage, and finally the hero gets a final battle with the bad guy and wins.

Even the action there is embarrassing... I mean come on, just 2 X-men side-kicks? That's it?

What makes this movie any interesting that people loved it, and got the movie to make more money than any other marvel movie in the last few years? Could someone explain why people loved it that much?

Comment: My opinion - as the answer below says - it was funny. IMHO there are now far too many superhero films, so many that only the 'different' ones stand out. Add to that the breaking the fourth wall bits and that sets it apart from other films. Again IMHO, superhero films are just a number of powerful characters beating the hell out of each other in a final climatic scene. Yes, Deadpool was that but it was funny and risqué too.

Comment: "Here it goes: A "hero" who wants something from a bad guy and pisses him off while trying to get it, and the bad guy takes the love of his life as a hostage, and finally the hero gets a final battle with the bad guy and wins." Apparently you don't like ANY super hero movies then... Because a lot of them follow this formula. It's not original, but it's not supposed to be original. It's supposed to be entertaining. And Deadpool kind of mocks the cliches.

Answer (score 12):

I can point out a lot of reasons. But most of them are about the main character himself: [**Deadpool**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool).

1. The most obvious reason is "**Humour**". Deadpool can be a pretty complex character, but one thing that is certain about him is humour, which contributed greatly to his movie becoming a people's fave. He's not only making fictional humour, as in, humour that only applies in the movie. In the movie, he makes fun of even Marvel itself, and other superheroes/movies like Wolverine and Green Lantern. 
   The character Deadpool (Ryan Reynolds), also played as another superhero in the movie Green Lantern, in which he had a green CGI animated suit. In the movie Deadpool, he says “don’t make the suit green or animated”, referring to his superhero suit, and poking fun at the suit he (Ryan Reynolds) wore in the movie Green Lantern. This makes him a different kind of superhero, not like the "standard" superheroes that are serious and uninteresting.
2. The **movie's length** is just perfect. A lot of superhero movies feel the need to be over two hours long! This movie is just **1 hour 48 minutes**. Just enough time to tell a story with some action and comedy without padding it out with pointless scenes
3. Deadpool contains very little racial, political and social conspiracy theories. Most superhero movies seem to have hidden political translations. An example is the **X-Men Franchise**. It draws deliberate parallels between the oppression of mutants and that of other marginalized groups, like the blacks and the LGBT community. But Deadpool doesn't contain any such content/tradition.
4. The movie is balanced. **It perfectly balances humour and drama/action**, without completely overwhelming the audience with either. The movie gives you enough drama without being totally overwhelming. Most movies tend to bore out the viewers by over-emphasis of an event or plot. For example, Deadpool suffered very much when he was experimented on. But his suffering is not forever showcased in the movie. Every movie with Wolverine (X-Men Character), who experienced the same suffering from the same types of experiments (from the same organisation too), is constantly darted with flashbacks and references to the times he suffered. In the end, it becomes depressing as the movie comes out to be a suffering story, rather than being an action feature.

Deadpool went through so much and is no longer mentally well or sane but is **ALLOWED** to be funny by the movie. If Marvel had gone with the tradition of their other movies, Deadpool would either be a "scary psychopath" or a "sociopath" with no feelings.

Deadpool is a unique and even uplifting portrayal of someone with mental health problems.

In conclusion, Deadpool is a likable, fun, compelling and even sympathetic character. And the movie is well crafted, and that's why people love it.

Comment: I would add that the way Deadpool upended the typical way that superhero stories are told is another factor in its success.